# Converting python 2D array to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading csv files where each row has different interpretation based on value of second field. Each row represents same type info  multiple times(repeated different columns values multiple time in a row). I need to read line by line and need to arrange it into different list of lists or 2 array.

```
Like:
with open('info.log','rt') as inputFile:
      filereader = csv.reader(inputFile, delimiter=',')
      for row in filereader:
          if (int(row[1]) == 5):
                for mylist in  (divide the long row into list of lists of fix N length) : # N will be number of columns here
                 array5.append(mylist[2:])   << Now this is an Array of  5 column.
                 # Or Can I append this list direct to dataframe A??

          elif (int(row[1]) == 4):
              for mylist in  (divide the long row into list of lists of fix M length):   # M will be number of columns here
                  array4.append(row[2:3]+mylist)
                  #Can I append this list direct to dataframe B??
```

After One file is parsed ,  have 2  2D arrays.  I have multiple  files to parse.
Now I want to run some analysis on that 2D array. Is better to convert 2D array into pandas dataframe?

Can I append each parsed row(list) into panda dataframe when I am parsing each row?

EDIT:

Adding the sample data:
Format of data presented in file is like that:

```
DATA,5,time, <IP1, IP2, write, read,error>, <IP1, IP2, write, read,error>, <IP1, IP2, write, read,error>, <IP1, IP2, write, read,error>....
DATA,4,time, <port_index, read_users, write_users > <port_index, read_users, write_users> <port_index, read_users, write_users>...


DATA,5,20180529235221,::127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1,0,33345,36736,36751,0,::ffff:127.0.0.1,::ffff:127.0.0.1,0,33346,36736,74690,0,::ffff:127.0.0.1,::ffff:127.0.0.1,0,33347,36736,36749,0,
DATA,4,20180529235251,0,4263532,464027, 2,4181981,2060546,3,4181981,2060546, 4,4181981,2060546, 5,4181981,2060546, 6,4263221,464221, 7,418332,206023,8,4181232,2060232, 9,418123,206023, 10,41812323,202456
DATA,5,20180529235221,::127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1,0,33345,36736,36751,0,::ffff:127.0.0.1,::ffff:127.0.0.1,0,33346,36736,74690,0,::ffff:127.0.0.1,::ffff:127.0.0.1,0,33347,36736,36749,0
DATA,5,20180529235221,::127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1,0,33345,36736,36751,0,::ffff:127.0.0.1,::ffff:127.0.0.1,0,33346,36736,74690,0,::ffff:127.0.0.1,::ffff:127.0.0.1,0,33347,36736,36749,0,
DATA,5,20180529235221,::127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1,0,33345,36736,36751,0,::ffff:127.0.0.1,::ffff:127.0.0.1,0,33346,36736,74690,0,::ffff:127.0.0.1,::ffff:127.0.0.1,0,33347,36736,36749,0,
DATA,4,20180529235251,0,4263532,464027, 2,4181981,2060546,3,4181981,2060546, 4,4181981,2060546, 5,4181981,2060546, 6,4263221,464221, 7,418332,206023,8,4181232,2060232, 9,418123,206023, 10,41812323,202456
```

Comment: To improve your question, and generate more helpful responses, I suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50766377/edit) your question to include some representative data.

Comment: As suggeted, added the sample data.

Comment: Can you show your expected output?